# [Flask]TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, flask

The code below is from 'Learn Python3 the Hard Way'. I am getting a GET instead of a POST request. The flask debugger points out the error in index on line
`'return render_template["hello_form.html"]'- TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable.`
This means that it is not entering the "POST" section. How do the forms work? Is
the html file correct? The template directory contains:

templates/hello_form.html

```
    <form action="/hello" method="POST">
        A Greeting: <input type="text" name="greet">
        </br>
        Your name: <input type="text" name="name">
        </br>
        <input type = "submit">
    </form>
```

templates/index.html

```
<body>
    {% if greeting %}
        I just wanted to say
        <em style="color: red; font-size: 2em;">{{ greeting }} </em>.
    {% else %}
        <em>Hello</em>, world!
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

app.py

```
@app.route("/hello", methods=['POST','GET'])
    def index():
        greeting = "Hello World"
        if request.method == "POST":
            name = request.form['name']
            greet = request.form['greet']
            greeting = f"{greet}, {name}"
            return render_template("index.html", greeting=greeting)
        else:
            return render_template["hello_form.html"]
```

[URL] http://localhost:5000/hello

Answer (score 0):

When you first go to `http://localhost:5000/hello`, that's a GET request, the POST request only happens when you submit the form.

The reason it's crashing is that you have square brackets instead of parentheses around "hello_form.html" (i.e. you're "subscripting" render_template like you would a dictionary instead of "calling" it like a function).

Here's how the code is meant to execute:

1. You go to `http://localhost:5000/hello`, which sends a `GET` request to `index`.
2. The `else` block executes and sends `hello_form.html` to your browser.
3. You enter a greeting and click "submit" on the form which sends a `POST` request with your greeting to `index`.
4. Now `index` runs a second time, but this time the `if` block *is* executed.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```py
@app.route("/hello", methods=['POST','GET'])
    def index():
        greeting = "Hello World"
        if request.method == "POST":
            # ...
        else:
            return render_template["hello_form.html"] # < --- this
```

To:

```py
@app.route("/hello", methods=['POST','GET'])
    def index():
        greeting = "Hello World"
        if request.method == "POST":
            # ...
        else:
            return render_template("hello_form.html") # < --- this
```

As @Xochozomatli has put it so well, you need to use a pair of parenthesis to call the function instead of square brackets that subscripts it.